# Windows batch file: find most recent file with space in name

Tags: windows, batch-file

This works except when there is space

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i
```

Is there a way if there is space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deal with the delimiters, because the default delimiters are the                                  and the <kbd>TAB</kbd>. My suggestion therefore is either use all tokens, `*`, or preferably no delimiters. It should also be noted that the default beginning of line, `EOL`, is the semicolon, `;`, so a robust command would prevent names beginning with that character from being omitted from the results too.

Using all tokens, and setting the beginning of line to a character which cannot be included as the first in a file or directory name:

```batch-file
For /F "EOL=? Tokens=*" %%I In ('Dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:C') Do Set "LAST=%%I"
```

*The very small, but possible, issue with this method is that filenames could begin with one or more space characters, and, as those are the default delimiters, they would be consumed and removed in the returned results.*

Using no delimiters and setting the beginning of line to a character which cannot be included as the first in a file or directory name:

```batch-file
For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:C') Do Set "LAST=%%I"
```

The above code examples will define the variable named `LAST`, with the name of each file, until all of the files have been iterated, *`set`ting each and overwriting the previous*. If you have a very large number of files in the, (current in this case), directory, you could alternatively reverse your sort method, *(instead of `/O:D` use `/O:-D`)*, define the first value, then break out of the loop:

```batch-file
For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /B /A:-D /O:-D /T:C') Do (
    Set "LAST=%%I"
    GoTo Done
)
:Done
```